# Visual Studio 2015 publish error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015 14.0.24720.00 Update 1

When publishing an MVC project to the file system the following errors arose:

1. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql, Version=10.3.0.0
2. The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager' threw an exception.

The solution was found here kind of buried in a different scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16864314/5647927

*"Look for a key in the registry under the following paths that points the the problem assembly and delete it:*

*HKLM\Software\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\msdeploy\3\extensibility*
*HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\msdeploy\3\extensibility*

*The problem registry key is installed by SQL."*

**Update**
Thanks to @paulsm4, alternative approaches, reported at [the referenced question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351289), that may work and  avoid editing the registry are:

- reinstall Web Deploy
- repair MS SQL server
- repair Visual Studio
- reinstall Visual Studio
- uninstall Microsoft dbsqlpackage provider

Comment: Good [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351289/), *NOT* necessarily a good solution. The better approach is usually to *repair* your (broken!) MSSQL install, not hack the registry.  Look at other posts in the same link for more details about alternative approaches.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running VS2015 Update 3 and this worked for me.

1. Close the VS IDE
2. Look for a key in the registry under the following paths that points the the problem assembly and then delete them:
   HKLM\Software\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\msdeploy\3\extensibility
   HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\msdeploy\3\extensibility
3. Re-launch the VS IDE and Publish your Web Job

Comment: magic, not sure what it did, but worked for me :) Thanks @NigelBelham