# The Type initializer for Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager threw an exception

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, webdeploy, azure-webjobs

Anyone have a solution for this?  I am trying to deploy an Azure Webjob using Visual Studio 2015 and it keep throwing this error whenever I try to validate the connection to the server.

I tried the solution in the first answer of this post, but I do not have those registry entries listed in the registry

[Web deployment task failed. (The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager' threw an exception.)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6351289/1462656)

I also tried to install the Web Deploy extension using nugget to the project.  Made no difference.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried other answers in that post you mentioned? Some said restart VS and rebuild the project fixed the problem, you could try it. The error message is quite general and doesn't provide much useful information to locate the root cause.

Comment: @forester123 yeah I did all that too, I'm currently trying a repair install on VS, hope that helps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web deployment task failed. (The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager' threw an exception.)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351289/web-deployment-task-failed-the-type-initializer-for-microsoft-web-deployment)

Answer (score 2):

If the repair doesn't work you could also try installing the latest version (3.6) of WebDeploy.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43717

You may be able to get more error details if you run MSDeploy from the command line with the `debug` flag.