# Exception during publishing web app to Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

We have created a sample Asp.net Core application. When we tried to publish the application into Azure we got following exception.

Web deployment task failed. (The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentManager' threw an exception.)

We have tried some solutions posted in some blogs but none got the issue resolved.

Comment: I suggest you re-try by installing the latest version of Web Deploy and check if that resolves your issue. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978696/the-type-initializer-for-microsoft-web-deployment-deploymentmanager-threw-an-exc

Comment: Could you show me some detail versions info you use? Like .net core version and what package you install?

Comment: I ran into the same issue. Any solution @kiran Wilson

Answer (score 2):

Here are some ways you could try:

1.Look for a key in the registry under the following paths that points the the problem assembly and delete it:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\msdeploy\3\extensibility
HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\msdeploy\3\extensibility
```

The problem registry key is installed by SQL.

2.Reinstall [Web Deploy](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) 3.5.

3.Uninstall `dbsqlpackage` provider . this packages no longer support.
4.Restarted Visual Studio and rebuilt the project.

For more details, you could refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351289/web-deployment-task-failed-the-type-initializer-for-microsoft-web-deployment).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to create a web job and publish it to a App Service in Azure.  To do this you have to create a Azure WebJob project type in visual studio.  To get this project type in VS you have to install it or download it using nuget.

Comment: Omg, Clippy .

Answer (score 0):

Installing "Web Deploy 3.5" extension helped me solve this issue.

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy